# Tabs in products page not woking

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, frontend, tabs

Suddenly the tabs in products stopped working. (products/description and reviews). I am using Madison magento theme.

Even I add description in back end it's not displayed any clues what might be the issue.

http://www.clients.avant8.com.au/nessco-pressure-systems/products/compressor-system/csk-compressor.html

Comment: This is most probably due to a Javascript and or CSS error. If you examine the source code of the page the description content is there but it is hidden with CSS

Comment: @ NathanielR Thanks for reply i will check that out.

Comment: this is not js/css error. you are using the magento rwd theme.check the catalog.xml file .you can use base theme files.

Comment: I have the same issue. What was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Best to start digging using chrome dev tools, viewing the console your getting some errors.

```
jquery.cycle2.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: e(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) 
@ jquery.cycle2.min.js:8(anonymous function) 
@ jquery.cycle2.min.js:8

app.js:918 Uncaught TypeError: dts.on is not a function(anonymous function) @ app.js:918x.extend.each 
@ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4x.fn.x.each 
@ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4(anonymous function) 
@ app.js:876x.Callbacks.c 
@ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4x.Callbacks.p.fireWith 
@ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4x.extend.ready 
@ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4q 
@ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
```

Your error is at:

```
//Toggle on tab (dt) click.
dts.on('click', function (e) {
```

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  This is my exact issue

Answer (score 1):

Yes, That is the jQuery error, you the default js or if you want to add the new one, add xyz.js file to only the product view page.

Then change accordingly.Go to your pdp page , check your html,and then give the id to the divs available for all three blocks.

You can then use the simple jquery as mention before:

```
jQuery(".viewreviews").click(function(){
        jQuery("div#viewreviews").show();
       jQuery(".viewreviews").addClass("current");
       jQuery(".brand, .details").removeClass("current");
        jQuery("div#details,div#brand").hide();
    });

    jQuery(".brand").click(function(){
        jQuery("div#brand").show();
        jQuery(".brand").addClass("current");
        jQuery(".viewreviews, .details").removeClass("current");
        jQuery("div#viewreviews,div#details").hide();
        jQuery("div#viewreviews,div#details").removeClass("current");
    });


        jQuery(".details").click(function(){
        jQuery(".details").addClass("current");
        jQuery("div#details").show();
        jQuery(".brand, .viewreviews").removeClass("current");
        jQuery("div#viewreviews,div#brand").removeClass("current");
        jQuery("div#viewreviews,div#brand").hide();
    });
```

Hope this helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old question, but posting my solution.

By default, my magento 1.9.2.2 was using jquery 1.10.2, but another extension was using jquery 1.4.0 which was conflicting with default one. I un-installed that extension as that was un-necessary (removed the functionality) and it worked.